# share profile doesn't work when applying to job

Tags: linkedin-api

The option to add social profile to when applying to a Splunk job is not working. When you click on the LinkedIn button it says "Page not found". The dead page link is https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorize?_l=en_US

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvnfm.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh1DO.png)

#linkedin

I tried sharing linkedin profile and it took me to a dead page.